# Counting matrices over finite fields of a given order

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

How can I count/enumerate matrices in ${\rm GL}(2,{\rm GF}(2^5))$
of order $3$? In general, how can I obtain the number of matrices in
${\rm GL}(2,{\rm GF}(q))$, where $q$ is a power of a prime, of order,
say, $t$?

Comment: You mean order in the group, i.e. minimal $t$ for which $A^t=1$?

Comment: Yes, something like, smallest t for which A^t=I_n. So the question is how many matrices A are there for a given t?

Answer (score 14):

Well, if $X^3=1$, then $(X-1)(X^2+X+1)=0$. At first, assume that 1 is eigenvalue of $X$, then the second eigenvalue $v$ belongs to the field $GF(32)$, so $v^3=v^{31}=1$, $v=1$. That is, $X=Id+Y$ for nilpotent $Y$, $X^3=Id+3Y=Id+Y$, $Y=0$, order of $X$ equals 1, not 3. So $X^2+X+1=0$, and this is both minimal and characteristic polynomial of $X$. So, we count number of quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ for which $a+d=1,ad-bc=1$. Fix arbitrary $d$ and arbitrary $c\ne 0$, then $a$ and $b$ are defined uniquely. Thus the answer is $32\cdot 31$.

In general case do the same steps, you have to know how many linear and quadratic factors does polynomial $X^t-1$ have in your field, this is standard (number of linear factors is $gcd(t,q-1)$, total degree of linear and quadratic factors is $gcd(t,q^2-1)$.)

Well, let me be more precise in this case. We count number $f(t)$ of solutions of equation $X^t=1$, then use Moebius inversion formula for count number of matrices of order $t$: it equals $\sum_{n|t} f(n)\mu(t/n)$.

We denote $m_1$ the number of linear factor of $X^t-1$, it equals $gcd(t,q-1)$, and $m_2$ the number of quadratic irreducible factors of $X^t-1$, we have $m_1+2m_2=gcd(t,q^2-1)$. There are $m_1$ scalar matrices $X$ and $(q+1)qm_1(m_1-1)/2$ diagonalizable but not scalar matrices ($q+1$ possible directions of first eigenvector, $m_1$ possible eigenvalues, then $q$ possible directions of second eigenvector and $m_1-1$ possible eigenvalues, each matrix is counted twice.) Now we count number of $X$ such that $X=c\cdot Id+Y$ with nilpotent $Y$ and some number $c$ such that $c^t=1$. We have $X^t=Id+tc^{t-1}Y$, thus we get $Y=0$ if $gcd(t,q)=1$ and any $Y$ is ok if $gcd(t,q)>1$. Nilpotent non-zero matrix is something like $\pmatrix{a&b\cr a^2/b&a}$, $b\ne 0$, or $\pmatrix{0&0\cr c&0},c\ne 0$. Totally, there are $q(q-1)+(q-1)=q^2-1$ nilpotent non-zero matrices, and $m_1(q^2-1)$ matrices $X=c\cdot Id+$(nilpotent), this is when $gcd(q,t)>1$.

Finally, we count matrices $X$ with irreducible characteristic polynomial $X^2+pX+q$ of degree 2, this polynomial is chosen between $m_2$ quadratic factors of $X^t-1$. It reduces to system of equations $a+d=p,ad-bc=q$. Fix arbitrary $d$ and arbitrary $c\ne 0$, then $a$ and $b$ are defined uniquely. Thus the answer is $q(q-1)$ matrices for each fixed polynomial, totally $m_2q(q-1)$ matrices.

Comment: many thanks for your answer it solves the problem.

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov, I have tried this and it works for t=3, however, over the same field, for t=11 and t=31, my computer results are different from those I compute by hand. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Also, is there a paper/book/any reference material where I can find this?

Comment: For $t=11$ we see that $x^{11}-1$ has 1 linear multiple $x-1$ and 5 quadratic multiples, that is, $m_1=1$, $m_2=5$. Thus we should have $1+5\cdot 32\cdot 31=4961$ matrices for which $X^{11}=1$, out of them there is 1 matrix of order 1 and 4960 matrices of order 11.

Comment: @ Fedor Petrov, checking the determinants of the elements (matrices) of order 3 in GL(2,GF(32)), I find that all elements have determinant equal to 1. Is this a mere coincidence?

Comment: If characteristic polynomial is $X^2+X+1$, then determinant is 1.

Comment: in one of your answers above you say that "this is standard ...total degree of linear and quadratic factors is gcd(t,$q^2−1$)". Is there a book which explains how to arrive at this?

Comment: @Mr.Kho total degree (not a number! above it is $m_1+2m_2$, not $m_1+m_2$) of linear and quadratic factors of a polynomial $g(x)\in \mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is a total number of roots of $g$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. For $g(x)=x^t-1$ it equals gcd$(t,q^2-1)$ as may be seen by considering a primitive root $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ and checking which powers of $\alpha$, $\beta=\alpha^s$, satisfy $\beta^t=1$.

Answer (score 5):

In [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), you can find the number of elements of order $t$
in ${\rm GL}(2,q)$ by the following function:

```
NumberOfElementsOfGivenOrderInGL2q := function ( q, t )
  return Sum(List(Filtered(ConjugacyClasses(GL(2,q)),
                           cl->Order(Representative(cl))=t),Size));
end;
```

For example in your case, i.e., $q = 2^5$ and $t = 3$, you obtain

```
gap> NumberOfElementsOfGivenOrderInGL2q(32,3);
992
```